# What was wrong with Nux (besides having delusions of grandeur) in Fury Road?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

What was the medical issue the character *Nux* was suffering from when he first hooked up with Max in *Fury Road*? If it was mentioned, I missed it.

Comment: There's a really good answer here that gives a medically plausible suggestion of what type of cancer Nux had and why blood transfusions would help treat it: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90240/31938 (questions might be duplicates?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's cancer. When talking to one of the wives, he mentions his two "mates" that will eventually kill him, "Larry" and "Barry", while pointing at two tumors in his neck.